# What is a viable combination for a Plasma Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I am looking into the different dragons to get a water and lightning combination in an attempt to produce the new Plasma Dragon for my park. What is a good combination of dragons to breed that will result in a quick turn around to try and optimize my chances of obtaining this breed of dragon? (I am currently trying water and storm dragons, but not much luck as of yet, hence my question.)

How do I breed a Plasma Dragon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a [Plasma Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Plasma_Dragon) all you need is a Lightening Dragon and a Water hybrid, or a Water Hybrid and a Lightening dragon. Water + lightening alone doesn't work since they can't breed.

Anything like **Iceberg + Lightening** or **Water + Cactus** should work well. They have an incubation time of 16 hours.

Comment: I am trying to find a combination that will produce very low breeding times when they are Not the Plasma dragon.